# Unable to see uploaded images on Azure Blob

Tags: angularjs, azure, image-upload, azure-blob-storage

I am new to azure blob storage and I am trying to upload image to blob storage. I am using angular at client end and uploaded image with following headers :

```
           'Content-type'
           'x-ms-blob-type'   
           'Content-Length'
```

my blob is saved and i can see it in Azure Portal. But I am not able to see images. I am unable to understand the reason.

Link of my client is http://educms.azurewebsites.net/#/pages/results

There is no button. as soon as you select an image file, it will get uploaded. You can see the uploaded file at https://hobcity.blob.core.windows.net/images2/filename.extension

Upload Code of AngularJs

```
       $scope.uploadFile = function(files) {
        var fd = new FormData();
        //Take the first selected file
        fd.append("file", files[0]);
        var size = files[0].size;
        var name = files[0].name;
        var type = files[0].type;
        var postData = {"name" : name};
        postData.containerName = 'images2';
        DataService.save('/tables/results/', postData).then(function(data){
          var header = {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                    'Content-type' : type,
                    'x-ms-blob-type' : 'BlockBlob',
                    'Content-Length' : size
            }
            var url = data.imageUri
            var queryString = data.sasQueryString
            var uploadUrl = url+ '/' + name + '/?'+queryString
            $http.put(uploadUrl, fd, {
            headers: header,
            transformRequest: angular.identity
        }).success(function(data){
                console.log(data)
            }).error(function(err){
                console.error(err);
            });

        });
    }
```

HTML :

code can be seen live at http://educms.azurewebsites.net/scripts/controllers/results.js

Anyone know what's wrong ?

Comment: Please ensure that your container's ACL is either blob or public and is not private.

Comment: @GauravMantri Even I thought that. It is public only... Still not working.

Comment: Oh ... I think I understood your question incorrectly. I believe your issue is that even though the image is being uploaded successfully, you can't see the image. Even if you download the image file, you can't open it in Paint or other image editing software. Is this correct? If that's the case, then can you please share the JS code for uploading. I uploaded a file and then downloaded it back and I'm not able to view that file. More than likely it is an issue with your upload code.

Comment: @GauravMantri : updated the code in question..

Answer (score 1):

So I uploaded a simple text file and traced the request through Fiddler. Here's what I saw:

```
PUT http://hobcity.blob.core.windows.net/images2/simpletextfile.txt/?se=2014-08-11T17%3A13%3A52Z&sr=c&sp=w&sig=SlY7wURwfSjM72Hw22507OHpnaCC1Ky6POk6hhR6fbU%3D HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Type: text/plain, multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------7de26921205a0
x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob
Referer: http://educms.azurewebsites.net/#/pages/results
Accept-Language: en-US
Origin: http://educms.azurewebsites.net
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Host: hobcity.blob.core.windows.net
Content-Length: 254
DNT: 1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache

-----------------------------7de26921205a0
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="simpletextfile.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

https://hobcity.blob.core.windows.net/images2/Add-Item.png
-----------------------------7de26921205a0--
```

I believe the reason you're running into the issue is because you're uploading the file as is (see your `Content-Type` is `multipart/form-data`) and this is corrupting the data. What you would need to do is read the file contents into a byte array and then upload that byte array. If you search for HTML 5 File API, you will find examples of how to read a file using JavaScript. Also I wrote a blog post about uploading files in Azure Blob Storage using JavaScript which you may find useful: http://gauravmantri.com/2013/12/01/windows-azure-storage-and-cors-lets-have-some-fun/ (though this post make use of jQuery instead of Angular but should give you some idea).

Comment: Hey, It worked... Thanks. I used filereader api and uploaded the byte-array. Thanks.. :)